# Android: creating a search, collecting values from different actvities

Tags: android, key-value

Iam about to create a search, But the point here is that Iam going to collect values from different activities, maybe I will store them in a keyvalue,

Where can I store the keyvalue object so I can reach from every activity without sending to eachother all the time?

---

okej, well iam going to store values, so i can sent to my service so it returns requested items (it means I will create a search)

Property Name 
ID
Selected Name

For example:
Proberty : Location 
selectedID = 36
selectedName = New York

By the way, I guess I can't use keyvaluepairs, what can I use if  I have three rows as in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you're storing, but I'm thinking storing everything in a SQLite database would be a good solution.